# upgrade manager just closes

Tags: upgrade

I keep on trying to upgrade this PC, but after getting the upgrade tool the distribution window closes and does not remember that I have tried upgrading. Is their any solution to this problem? I am upgrading form 10.04 to 10.10. Thank you.

Comment: Updated the Ubuntu 9.10 and rebooted now Update Manager disappears when you try to use it

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you report a bug by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then entering `ubuntu-bug update-manager`. This will allow the developers to help improve Ubuntu. (The same procedure is used for any application.)

Answer (score 0):

I will commit a small heresy and say, upgrades don't always work. If you have lots of outside sources from PPAs and have applications on your system that are not standard releases, perhaps obtained by PPA or compiled yourself, it causes problems with the upgrade. Then you may have no alternative but to identify those packages and roll back to the standard Ubuntu versions. Then try again. In the worst case, you may need to do a fresh installation.

See: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29584/safely-remove-ppas-and-roll-back-to-stable-versions-in-ubuntu/

Fresh installations are nothing to be feared. You get a clean slate. I always do them and it is a piece of cake.

My method is to first have a separate home partition. If you don't have this then you have to go through the added step of copying the files from your home folder to another device, such as a usb stick (make sure that you get the hidden files too, Ctrl+H). My home partition is at least five years old and I have re-used it at least 20 times and never backed up or saved anything, without any data loss. So much for the advantage of re-using a separate home...

The next step is to save your list of installed applications. You can use the commandline, but I prefer Synaptic. You open Synaptic and go to File, Save Markings (tick the box for full state). Give it a name and put it in a safe place, such as on your usb stick. Re-install. Re-boot. If necessary re-copy files back to home. Open Synaptic. Go to File, Read Markings and navigate to the text file. Apply and do something else till it is done.

Try the roll back idea first, if fresh installations scare you (it's almost Hallowe'en afterall). Booh! :)

Comment: The upgrade tool already disables PPAs before attempting an upgrade.